# how to replace the right opening and end tags

Tags: javascript

I want to replace a specific `<span class="externallink::>` opening tag and an ending tag, to a link tag. This works great if there were no other span tags like `<span class="weight-bold">text</span>`.

My code transforms also the `<span class="weight-bold">text</span>` to `<span class="weight-bold">text</a>`. How to avoid that? I only want to change the opening and ending spans with the class `class="externallink::`.

```
var spanClass3 = 'Ab 1870 ist die <span class="weight-bold">Direction des Musées nationaux</span>eine Außendienststelle der Administration des Beaux-Arts <span class="weight-bold  ">Jacques Jaujard</span>Kunstwerke der Musées nationaux in verschiedene Depots Frankreichs organisiert. Während der deutschen Besatzung unterstützt er die Unternehmungen Rose Vallands im Musée du Jeu de Paume.leitet sein Sekretariat von 1941-1944.<br><span class="weight-bold  "> Rose Valland</span> beginnt ihre Karriere im Jahr 1932 als freiwillige Mitarbeiterin im Musée des Écoles <span class="externallink::https://www.siv.archivesnationales.culture.gouv.fr">Articles 1 à 20</span> étrangères contemporaines des Jeu de Paume. <span class="externallink::https://www.google.com">Articles 2 à 20</span>';

var check = spanClass3.includes('externallink::');

if ( check == true ) {
  spanClass3 = spanClass3.replace('<span class="externallink::', '<a href="');
  spanClass3 = spanClass3.replace('foreground-blue underline-1', '');
  spanClass3 = spanClass3.replace('</span>', '</a>');        
}
```

Right now I'm getting only the first link to work.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Do not do DOM operations with strings.

Answer (score 3):

I would try not to ever use regex on HTML

I use

- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to find classes that begins with `"externallink..` ([`^=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax)),
- [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and
- [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild). You can use [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith) if you do not need to support IE

Note I also use [`backticks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to allow newlines in the string

```js
const spanClass3 = `Ab 1870 ist die <span class="weight-bold">Direction des Musées nationaux</span>eine Außendienststelle der Administration des Beaux-Arts <span class="weight-bold">Jacques Jaujard</span>Kunstwerke der Musées nationaux in verschiedene Depots Frankreichs organisiert. Während der deutschen Besatzung unterstützt er die Unternehmungen Rose Vallands im Musée du Jeu de Paume.leitet sein Sekretariat von 1941-1944.<br><span class="weight-bold">
Rose Valland</span> beginnt ihre Karriere im Jahr 1932 als freiwillige Mitarbeiterin im Musée des Écoles <span class="externallink::https://www.siv.archivesnationales.culture.gouv.fr">Articles 1 à 20</span> étrangères contemporaines des Jeu de Paume. <span class="externallink::https://www.google.com">Articles 2 à 20</span>';`

let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = spanClass3;
[...div.querySelectorAll("[class^=externallink]")].forEach(function(span) {
  let anchor = document.createElement("a")
  anchor.href = span.className.split("::")[1];
  anchor.innerHTML = span.innerHTML;
  span.parentNode.replaceChild(anchor, span); 
})
document.body.appendChild(div)
```

```css
.weight-bold {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

Without IE (or needing Babel)

```js
const spanClass3 = `Ab 1870 ist die <span class="weight-bold">Direction des Musées nationaux</span>eine Außendienststelle der Administration des Beaux-Arts <span class="weight-bold  ">Jacques Jaujard</span>Kunstwerke der Musées nationaux in verschiedene Depots Frankreichs organisiert. Während der deutschen Besatzung unterstützt er die Unternehmungen Rose Vallands im Musée du Jeu de Paume.leitet sein Sekretariat von 1941-1944.<br><span class="weight-bold">
Rose Valland</span> beginnt ihre Karriere im Jahr 1932 als freiwillige Mitarbeiterin im Musée des Écoles <span class="externallink::https://www.siv.archivesnationales.culture.gouv.fr">Articles 1 à 20</span> étrangères contemporaines des Jeu de Paume. <span class="externallink::https://www.google.com">Articles 2 à 20</span>';`

let div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = spanClass3;
div.querySelectorAll("[class^=externallink]").forEach(span => {
  let anchor = document.createElement("a");
  anchor.href = span.className.split("::")[1];
  anchor.innerHTML = span.innerHTML;
  span.replaceWith(anchor); 
})
document.body.appendChild(div)
```

```css
.weight-bold {
  font-weight: bold
}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what `[class^=externallink]` does and/or adding a link to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax).